# CSS table row reorganisation

Tags: css, html-table

I want to move the last row of a table on top and shift all other rows one down. I tried what works for divs, but unfortunatelly it wont work for table rows.

HTML I used

```css
.tablebodyclass tr {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.tablebodyclass tr:last-of-type {
  top: 0px;
  bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tbody class="tablebodyclass">

    <tr class="no-stripe hidden" style="display: table-row;">
      <td class="align-right" colspan="3">bla bla1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="no-stripe hidden" style="display: table-row;">
      <td class="align-right" colspan="3">bla bla2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="no-stripe hidden" style="display: table-row;">
      <td class="align-right" colspan="3">bla bla3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="no-stripe hidden" style="display: table-row;">
      <td><strong>THIS needs to be first</strong> </td>
      <td class="align-right" colspan="2">xxxxxx
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3ow0mrvy/1/

any hint on how to reorder table rows are highly appreicated

--endo

Comment: You can either use div structure with display:flex; and order property or jquery to accomplish this!

Comment: @CodeGator unfortunatelly i cant change the html, so i have only css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reorder the rows with only CSS. jQuery or flexbox could help you out there. However, to mimic this with pure CSS, you could add a margin to the top row, and then set the last row to be `position: absolute` to make it appear on top:

```css
.tablebodyclass tr {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.tablebodyclass tr:last-of-type {
  top: 0px;
  bottom: auto;
}

tr:last-of-type {
  position: absolute;
}

tr:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 14px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-vertical-middle table-shop table-stack-phone">
  <tbody class="tablebodyclass">
    <tr class="no-stripe hidden" style="display: block;">
      <td class="align-right" colspan="3">bla bla1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="no-stripe hidden" style="display: block;">
      <td class="align-right" colspan="3">bla bla2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="no-stripe hidden" style="display: block;">
      <td class="align-right" colspan="3">bla bla3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="no-stripe hidden" style="display: block;">
      <td><strong>THIS needs to be first</strong> </td>
      <td class="align-right" colspan="2">xxxxxx
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ow0mrvy/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex and order in order to achieve what you want.

```css
tbody tr{

  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-vertical-middle table-shop table-stack-phone">                                    

<tbody class="tablebodyclass" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">

<tr class="no-stripe hidden" style="order: 2;">
  <td class="align-right" colspan="3">bla bla1</td>
</tr>

<tr class="no-stripe hidden" style="order: 3;">
  <td class="align-right" colspan="3">bla bla2</td>
</tr>

<tr class="no-stripe hidden" style="order: 4;" >
  <td class="align-right" colspan="3">bla bla3</td>
</tr>
        
<tr class="no-stripe hidden" style="order: 1;">
  <td><strong>THIS needs to be first</strong> </td>
  <td class="align-right" colspan="2">xxxxxx
</tr>             
</tbody>    
</table>
```

To learn more about how flex works you can look into this [great article].(https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: This is not a good idea in general - using flexbox will make the table lose its default layout characteristics. (For example the cells in different rows will not be aligned any more.)

Comment: Yes I also think so but, it's not so easy to re-order the rows using table layout. And if this fulfills his purpose I think it's good to go. I think it completely depends upon the need of the application.